# Flutter test gives me "No method stub was called" even though I have a method defined

Tags: flutter, mockito

```
abstract class HttpService {
  Future<http.Response> fetchData();
}

class MockApiService implements HttpService {
  @override
  Future<http.Response> fetchData() async {
    return http.Response('Mocked Response', 200);
  }
}

Future<http.Response> helperFunc() async {
  return http.Response('Mocked Response', 200);
  ;
}

void main() {
  group('API Tests', () {
    test('Mock API Request', () async {
      final mockApiService = MockApiService();
      when(mockApiService.fetchData())
          .thenAnswer((realInvocation) async => helperFunc());

      verify(mockApiService.fetchData()).called(1);
    });
  });
}
```

I'm not sure as to why it gives me the error "Bad state: No method stub was called from within `when()`. Was a real method called, or perhaps an extension method?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should extend from Mock on your `MockApiService` class.

```dart
class MockApiService extends Mock implements HttpService {
...
}
```

If you want to implement your own try a [`Fake`](https://pub.dev/packages/mockito#writing-a-fake)